# Setting up multi module packages in Intellij

Tags: java, gradle, intellij-idea

When I set the src folder in Intellij as `Set as source root` the folders under it main->java->restservice all becomes packages. In a standalone project it would not be the case and only the last folder `restservice` would become the package. I made my project in a new IntelliJ Gradle project. But then I had to put it into a new repository under a folder. The final structure looks like this:
[image]

Here the files Application, Controller, Model.java, Utils, and the above folder structure is what I have added. The new repo `auto` had an empty `auto-api` folder and also some Gradle files. Since I created the files under `restservice` package in a separate IntelliJ. It had its own Gradle files.
**Some questions:**

- I am not sure if I should put them there or use the Gradle files in the top folder.
- Apart from that, there is some issue with the folder structure which is causing the main and java folders also be treated as packages
- Is it a good idea to create the `auto-api` as a module rather than a directory? Then it will be a submodule inside the `auto` module

Comment: It is not recommended to set content roots via IDE settings when using Maven/Gradle because these settings will be lost after the project reimport. Please use build.gradle for that purpose. See also https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/organizing_gradle_projects.html

Comment: @EgorKlepikov the top folder `auto` is a module and the one under it `auto-api` is a directory. I am not sure how do I add code inside the directory because if I right click on it I only see options to create Files and Directories